# How many of such OR how many such

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

1 How many such people do you know?

2 How many of such people do you know?

I have come across both versions. I still don't know which one is correct.

Comment: It's [***far more common***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many+such%2Cmany+of+such&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20of%20such%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmany%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20of%20such%3B%2Cc0) NOT to include the preposition *(**of**)* between ***many*** and ***such*** in such contexts, as that linked NGram chart shows. But in most if not all cases, you ***can*** include it if you want. I can't think of any context where this could affect the meaning.

Comment: Hmm, to me "how many of such" sounds very unidiomatic. "How many of those people" or even "How many of those kind of people" would be OK.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Admittedly there are only 3-4 written instances of [***How many of such people are there?***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22how+many+of+such+people+are+there%22) in Google Books. But they're in the context of parliamentary debates, court judgements, and literary analysis - all pretty good company, I'd say! :)

Comment: I just wanted to ask, I see people answer the question in the comments all the time instead of making an answer when it says specifically not to do that every time you start writing a comment. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @salt The comment boilerplate is the same across the network, but actual comment practice and content differ by site. Here people often share an easy answer in a comment when they don't have time to write a well-formed, sourced answer. Theoretically it's discouraged. Mods can, however, convert great comments to answers.